# Find All Post By User ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use mongoose to populate "Post Schema" with information about users whic create the post.

**postModule.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
title:String,
description:String,
datePost:Date,
images:[String],
like:[String],
dislike:[String],
author:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
},
 });


postSchema.pre(/^find/,function(next){
this.populate({
    path:'author',
    select:'photo firstName lastName'
  });
next();
});


 const Post = mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
 module.exports = Post;
```

This is the controller build in **postController.js**

```
//Get All User Post
exports.getUsersPost = catchAsync(async(req,res,nex)=>{
const userPost = await Post.find({author:req.params.userId});

res.status(200).json({
    status:"success",
    length:userPost.length,
    data:{
        post:userPost
    }
});
});
```

**postRouter.js**

```
router.route('/get-user-posts/:userId').get(authController.protect,postController.getUsersPost)
```

I don't know what is wrong, I recive in postman this error 

```
Cannot GET /api/v1/get-user-posts/5f719092ba22b8373c72196
```


There is any option to resolve this problem and the result of request it must to by all the posts created by the user.

Comment: Can you post your `index.js` or server start file  where your registered your routes?

Comment: **app.js**//App Routes
const sessionRoutes = require('./routes/sessionsRoutes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const viewRoutes = require('./routes/viewRoutes');
const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes');

//Api Routes
app.use('/api/v1/session',sessionRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/user',userRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/post',postRoutes);
app.use('/',viewRoutes);


module.exports = app;

Comment: mongoose find multiple conditions this is what I need to do but in my code dosen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `app.js` looks like below, then you endpoint should be:

`/api/v1/post/get-user-posts/5f719092ba22b8373c72196`.

It takes the whole string in the `use()` function. So `/api/v1/user/**Routes you've defined in your Routes files**`

```
const sessionRoutes = require('./routes/sessionsRoutes'); 
    const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes'); 
    const viewRoutes = require('./routes/viewRoutes'); 
    const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes'); 
    
    app.use('/api/v1/session',sessionRoutes); 
    app.use('/api/v1/user',userRoutes); 
    app.use('/api/v1/post',postRoutes); 
    app.use('/',viewRoutes); 
    module.exports = app;
```

Also add and extra slash just to be sure `app.use('/api/v1/user/', userRoutes)`